# Select records for two tables where any parameter can be empty

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am using SQL Server 2008, and development in C#. I just started it a week. and stuck with this scenario. I have two tables

**Table 1**:

```
EMID    EMNA        EMCN
---------------------------
1       Junaid      1347609
2       Jhon        1347610
3       Shwan       1347611
4       ABC         1347612
```

**Table 2**:

```
EMCN        ALDT        ALTM
--------------------------------
1347609     12/21/2015  52:00.0
1347609     12/21/2015  30:00.0
1347610     12/21/2015  50:00.0
1347610     12/22/2015  30:00.0
1347611     12/23/2015  50:00.0
1347611     12/21/2015  43:00.0
1347609     12/30/2015  25:00.0
1347611     12/29/2015  13:00.0
1347611     12/28/2015  43:00.0
1347609     12/27/2015  24:00.0
1347610     12/26/2015  03:00.0
```

Required output:

```
    EMNA    ALDT        ALTM
    -------------------------
    Junaid  30-Dec-2015 16:25
    Jhon    29-Dec-2015 20:13
    Shawn   28-Dec-2015 06:43
    Junaid  27-Dec-2015 15:24
    Jhon    26-Dec-2015 10:03
    Shawn   23-Dec-2015 11:50
    Jhon    22-Dec-2015 13:30
    Junaid  21-Dec-2015 09:30
    Jhon    21-Dec-2015 18:50
    Junaid  21-Dec-2015 14:52
    Shawn   21-Dec-2015 09:43
```

User can select multiple employees and date range and any field can be null, in SQL Server this query return results, but in C# I am not able to get the results. The problem is with `IN()`, if no user is selected i.e `EMID` is blank it should return all records for selected date range. If one date is select it should return result for that date only

SQL query

```
Declare @EMID int;
Declare @FromDate date;
Declare @ToDate date;

if @FromDate is null
   SET @FromDate = @ToDate;

if @ToDate is null
   SET @ToDate = @FromDate;

Select  
    E.EMNA,  
    REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT (varchar, c.ALDT, 106),11),' ','-') AS ALDT,  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),c.ALTM , 108) AS ALTM 
from 
    Table1 E 
join
    Table2 C on E.EMCN = C.EMCN
where
    (E.EMID IN(@EMID) OR @EMID IS NULL) 
    and (c.ALDT > @FromDate OR @FromDate IS NULL) 
    and (c.ALDT < dateadd(day,1,@ToDate) OR @ToDate IS NULL)
order by  
    C.ALDT DESC
```

SQL string

```
string strSqlQuery = string.Format(@"    
Declare @EMID int;
Declare @FromDate date;
Declare @ToDate date;
SET @EMID = {0};
SET @FromDate = '{1}';

if @FromDate is null
   SET @FromDate = @ToDate;

SET @ToDate = '{2}';

if @ToDate is null
   SET @ToDate = @FromDate;

Select  
    E.EMNA,  
    REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT (varchar, c.ALDT, 106),11),' ','-') AS ALDT,  
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),c.ALTM , 108) AS ALTM 
from 
    A01001 E 
join 
    A01008 C on E.EMCN = C.EMCN
where
    (E.EMID IN(@EMID) OR @EMID IS NULL) 
    and (c.ALDT > @FromDate OR @FromDate IS NULL) 
    and (c.ALDT < dateadd(day, 1, @ToDate) OR @ToDate IS NULL)
order by
    Y C.ALDT DESC", 
    objCabinet.strEmployeeId, strFromDate,objCabinet.strToDate);
```

How can I fix this query or my string to get it working for following scenario

- multiple employees are selected but not date range
- multiple employees are selected with date range
- multiple employee are selected with one date

I created a stored procedure but its not returning values .

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sptEmpCabAccess]
     @EMID int = null,
     @FromDate date = null,
     @ToDate date = null
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@FromDate IS NULL)
        SET @FromDate = @ToDate;

    IF (@ToDate IS NULL)
        SET @ToDate = @FromDate;

    Select  
        E.EMNA,  
        REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT (varchar, c.ALDT, 106),11),' ','-') AS ALDT,  
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),c.ALTM , 108) AS ALTM 
    from 
        A01001 AS E 
    join
        A01008 AS C on E.EMCN = C.EMCN
    where
        (E.EMID IN(@EMID) OR @EMID IS NULL) 
        and (c.ALDT > @FromDate OR @FromDate IS NULL) 
        and (c.ALDT < dateadd(day,1,@ToDate) OR @ToDate IS NULL)
    order by
        C.ALDT DESC
    END
GO
```

C# code calling the stored procedure:

```
using (SqlConnection objsqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn))
{
    objsqlconn.Open();

    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("sptEmpCabAccess", objsqlconn))
        {
            objcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            objcmd.Parameters.Add("@EMID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = objCabinet.strEmployeeId;
            objcmd.Parameters.Add("@FromDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = objCabinet.strFromDate; ;
            objcmd.Parameters.Add("@ToDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = objCabinet.strToDate;

            // error here cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'system.data.dataset'
            dsGetData = objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use stored procedures? This is a definite no in C#.

Comment: I created one but its not returning value, updated the question

Comment: `objCabinet.strFromDate,objCabinet.strToDate` values are `NULLABLE`

Comment: If your query works, your SP should work too. Can you publish the code of your SP? Also the C# code that you wrote to call the SP.

Comment: done, both store procedure and c sharp code added, and yes values are NULLABLE

Answer (score 0):

You need to change query where you are applying filters, in place of checking with Null assign some default values like

1) Declare @EMID int=0;

2) WHERE (E.EMID IN(@EMID) OR @EMID=0)

Comment: Remove other date filters for test and just run                            WHERE (E.EMID =@EMID OR @EMID=0). This must be working give a try.

Comment: How it can be when there is no record associate with this ID, i tried but no result